# Strange tensorflow issue: dropped ranks

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am uncertain what is happening here. I have been reading about this error and I interpret it as an error related to image reshape. For some reason, the last 3 ranks are missing. The data set has each image that are non-normalized in width and height. The images are supposed to be a square after processing, which is where the resize function of scikit is failing to fill the space. Instead it is putting into train_X a proportionally scaled set based from the maximum dimension. Here is an idea of the flow.

```
def read_img(file):  
    img = skimage.io.imread(img_folder + file)
    img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (img_height, img_width), mode='reflect')

    return img[:,:,:img_channels] #the last 3 ranks meant to fill in the traceback
```

The read_img function feeds into train_X.

```
train_X = np.stack(train_['file'].apply(read_img))
```

Here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "A:\anoth\...\newmodel.py", line 196, in <module>
generator, train_X, val_X, test_X, train_y, val_y, test_y = 
prepare2train(train_, val_, test_, 'Category')
File "A:\anoth\...\newmodel.py", line 192, in prepare2train
generator.fit(train_X,augment=True, rounds=50, seed=43)
File "A:\anoth\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image.py", line 1347, in fit
'Got array with shape: ' + str(x.shape))
ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (6848,)
```

Am I understanding this problem correctly? If so, why might train_X drop the last 3 ranks? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Done. Definition added.

Comment: Train .. Splits and balances the dataset. I have used the code before and it works on jpgs. I am beginning to suspect it is related to the structure of img arrays into read files. The code works on jpgs but pngs might have a structure conflicting with the read file img return output.

Answer (score 0):

img = skimage.transform.resize(img, (img_height, img_width), mode='reflect') for some reason is not appropriately resizing the images. Resizing the images outside of python and not using this line of code resolved the problem of dropped ranks.